# How to Delete an Item from Arraylist in SharedPreferences with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I was trying to save the array's data in shared prefrences and two problems occured.

The first one is that every time I open the activity that should have the array in it (mainPage activity) it doesn't show anything until I add use the foodAdding activity to add food and then it shows all the previous foods and shows the food that I have just added

The second one is that whenever I try to delete any of the elements it get deleted till I refresh the activity or go to another activity and come back so how could I delete elements properly in the shared prefrences ??

the code for the mainPage activity (the activity that should show all the foods):

```
package com.example.yourhealthapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class mainPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button adding;
    Button main;
    Button profile;
    public static ArrayList<Food> foods = new ArrayList<Food>();
    FoodAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

        adapter = new FoodAdapter(this, foods);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int weight = intent.getIntExtra("weight", 404);
        int height = intent.getIntExtra("height", 404);
        int age = intent.getIntExtra("age", 404);
        adding = findViewById(R.id.adding_main);
        main = findViewById(R.id.main_main);
        profile = findViewById(R.id.profile_main);
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                final int item = position;
                new AlertDialog.Builder(mainPage.this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_delete).setTitle("Are you sure ?").setMessage("Do you want to delete this meal ?")
                .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        foods.remove(item);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("no", null).show();

                return true;
            }
        });
        adding.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent next_page = new Intent(mainPage.this, foodadding.class);
                next_page.putExtra("weight", weight);
                next_page.putExtra("height", height);
                next_page.putExtra("age", age);
                startActivity(next_page);
            }
        });
        main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent next_page = new Intent(mainPage.this, mainPage.class);
                next_page.putExtra("weight", weight);
                next_page.putExtra("height", height);
                next_page.putExtra("age", age);
                startActivity(next_page);
            }
        });
        profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent next_page = new Intent(mainPage.this, profile.class);
                next_page.putExtra("weight", weight);
                next_page.putExtra("height", height);
                next_page.putExtra("age", age);
                startActivity(next_page);
            }
        });
        loadData();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void loadData()
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString("meals list", null);
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Food>>() {}.getType();
        foods = gson.fromJson(json, type);

        if (foods == null)
        {
            foods = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
    
}
```

The code for the foodAdding activity (the activity that you add the foods from):

```
package com.example.yourhealthapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class foodadding extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button adding;
    Button main;
    Button profile;
    Button add;
    Button dont;
    EditText calories;
    EditText servings;
    EditText grams;
    EditText name;
    mainPage array = new mainPage();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_foodadding);
        adding = findViewById(R.id.adding_food);
        main = findViewById(R.id.main_food);
        profile = findViewById(R.id.profile_food);
        add = findViewById(R.id.add);
        dont = findViewById(R.id.dont);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        int weight = i.getIntExtra("weight", 404);
        int height = i.getIntExtra("height", 404);
        int age = i.getIntExtra("age", 404);
        grams = findViewById(R.id.grams);
        calories = findViewById(R.id.calories);
        servings = findViewById(R.id.servings);
        name = findViewById(R.id.name);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Food w = new Food(name.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(calories.getText().toString()) , Integer.parseInt(servings.getText().toString()), Integer.parseInt(grams.getText().toString()));
                array.foods.add(w);
                saveData();
            }
        });
        dont.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String q = name.getText().toString();
                q = "How many calories there are in one serving of" + q;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH );
                intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, q);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        adding.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent next_page = new Intent(foodadding.this, foodadding.class);
                next_page.putExtra("weight", weight);
                next_page.putExtra("height", height);
                next_page.putExtra("age", age);
                startActivity(next_page);
            }
        });
        main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent next_page = new Intent(foodadding.this, mainPage.class);
                next_page.putExtra("weight", weight);
                next_page.putExtra("height", height);
                next_page.putExtra("age", age);
                startActivity(next_page);
            }
        });
        profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent next_page = new Intent(foodadding.this, profile.class);
                next_page.putExtra("weight", weight);
                next_page.putExtra("height", height);
                next_page.putExtra("age", age);
                startActivity(next_page);
            }
        });

    }
    public void saveData()
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(array.foods);
        editor.putString("meals list", json);
        editor.apply();
    }

}
```

And I want as well to save the info that I created using the user's input in this activity (profile) so how could I do that ?

the code for the profile activity is :

```
package com.example.yourhealthapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import java.lang.Math;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class profile extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button adding;
    Button main;
    Button profile;
    Button edit;
    int caleaten = 0 ;
    MainActivity info = new MainActivity();
    mainPage fo = new mainPage();
    TextView gain;
    TextView loose;
    TextView maintain;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        adding = findViewById(R.id.adding_profile);
        main = findViewById(R.id.main_profile);
        maintain = findViewById(R.id.maintain);
        edit = findViewById(R.id.edit);
        loose = findViewById(R.id.loosing);
        gain = findViewById(R.id.gaining);
        profile = findViewById(R.id.profile_profile);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int weight = intent.getIntExtra("weight", 404);
        int height = intent.getIntExtra("height", 404);
        int age = intent.getIntExtra("age", 404);
        double maintanancem = (10 * weight) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age) + 5;
        double maintainancew = (10 * weight) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age) - 161;
        if(info.active == "low physical activity")
        {
            maintainancew *= 1.375;
            maintanancem *= 1.375;
        }
        else if(info.active == "average physical activity")
        {
            maintainancew *= 1.550;
            maintanancem *= 1.550;
        }
        else
        {
            maintainancew *= 1.725;
            maintanancem *= 1.725;
        }
        for (int i = 0 ; i < fo.foods.size(); i++)
        {
            caleaten += fo.foods.get(i).getmCalories() * fo.foods.get(i).getmServings();
        }
        maintanancem -= caleaten;
        maintainancew -= caleaten;
        if (info.g == "male" )
        {
            maintain.setText(Integer.toString((int)maintanancem));
            gain.setText(Integer.toString((int)maintanancem + 500));
            loose.setText(Integer.toString((int) (maintanancem - 500)));
        }
        else
        {
            maintain.setText(Integer.toString((int)maintainancew));
            gain.setText(Integer.toString((int)maintainancew + 500));
            loose.setText(Integer.toString((int)maintainancew - 500));
        }


        adding.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent next_page = new Intent(profile.this, foodadding.class);
                next_page.putExtra("weight", weight);
                next_page.putExtra("height", height);
                next_page.putExtra("age", age);
                startActivity(next_page);
            }
        });
        edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(profile.this , MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent next_page = new Intent(profile.this, mainPage.class);
                next_page.putExtra("weight", weight);
                next_page.putExtra("height", height);
                next_page.putExtra("age", age);
                startActivity(next_page);
            }
        });
        profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent next_page = new Intent(profile.this, profile.class);
                next_page.putExtra("weight", weight);
                next_page.putExtra("height", height);
                next_page.putExtra("age", age);
                startActivity(next_page);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Save the Json as a Hash Set. this way editing the list would be simple.
and after editing you can save it in the same shared preference

Comment: Can you please tell me how because I am new to android development